# Get from a multimensional array only one sub-array by conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this array :

```
[
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 's'}, 
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 58), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 's'}, 
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 56, 51), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 'm'}
 ]
```

I want to get only one sub array that correspond on 2 conditions :

`1 : createdAt is bigger`

`2 : data_type = s`

Is possible to do this thing by using some libraries ?

I trying like this :

```
dataToReturn = []

    for data in datas:
        if date_type in data['data_type']:
            dataToReturn.append(data['data_type'])
    return dataToReturn
```

But seems is not the better idea.

Expected output :

```
['createdAt' : datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41), 'rawValue' : -200.0]
```

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: I edited the question @Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

d = [
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 's'}, 
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 58), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 's'}, 
  {u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 56, 51), u'rawValue': -200.0, u'data_type': 'm'}
 ]

value = [i for i in d if i["data_type"] == "s"]
res = sorted(value, key=lambda x: x["createdAt"], reverse=True)
print(res[0])
print(len(value))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'data_type': 's', u'rawValue': -200.0, u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41)}
2
```

- `[i for i in d if i["data_type"] == "s"]` to get dict with `data_type` == "s"
- Use `sorted` to sort by datetime and then use index

Comment: exist a possibility to get the number of items in array, for example I want the number of sub arrays with data_type = "s", in my case, the count = 2 ?

Comment: Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` to find the sub array that has biggest `createdAt` time

```
>>> import datetime
>>> lst = [{u'data_type': 's', u'rawValue': -200.0, u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41)}, {u'data_type': 's', u'rawValue': -200.0, u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 58)}, {u'data_type': 'm', u'rawValue': -200.0, u'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 56, 51)}]
>>> {str(k):v for k,v in max(filter(lambda x: x['data_type'] == 's', lst), key=lambda x: x['createdAt']).items() if str(k) in ['createdAt', 'rawValue']}
{'rawValue': -200.0, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 3, 41)}
```